# Misunstanding Rectangle.Intersect(r1,r2), not reporting .Size as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, system.drawing, window-managers

I am attempting to write a program that considers `Screen` `Bounds` and if a window spans multiple screens, the window will "snap" to the closest edge of the `Screen` which the window has the most area in.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

Rectangle rct = new Rectangle();
GetWindowRect(hwnd, ref rct);

if (rct.IntersectsWith(Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds))
{
    Rectangle hwndinterwithscreen = Rectangle.Intersect(rct, Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds);
    MessageBox.Show("hwnd: " + hwnd.ToInt32().ToString() + " intersects with: " + Screen.AllScreens[0].DeviceName + " at: " + hwndinterwithscreen.Location + " that is this big: " + hwndinterwithscreen.Size);
}
}
```

With the above, I am seeing very strange results:
1) If the center of the top message bar is moved off `Screen.AllScreens[0]`, but still overlaps with `Screen.AllScreens[0]`, the conditional isn't entered.
2) `hwndinterwithscreen.Size` changes every time I move the window, and seems to be consider the closest border of `Screen.AllScreens[0]` in the `hwndinterwithscreen` calculation.

Unless I am misunderstanding what is very clear documentation on [System.Drawing.Rectangle.Intersect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y10fyck0.aspx), something is abnormal.

Why is `hwndinterwithscreen.Size` reporting different numbers.

Comment: GetWindowRect() doesn't return a Rectangle, it returns a RECT.  Which has a very different definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the **wrong structure** `Rectangle` in the `GetWindowRect` function, you have to use [the `RECT` structure](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/RECT.html) which can be defined like this:

```
public struct RECT {
   public int left, top, right, bottom;
}
```

However, to get the `Screen` in which the window has the most intersection, you can try using the static method `Screen.FromControl`:

```
Screen scr = Screen.FromControl(yourForm);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am attempting to pull the intersecting area of other `hwnd` not my form(s), so I don't think that method will work (?).

Comment: @mbrownnyc of course, it won't but we have the static method `Screen.FromHandle`, you can use it instead.